# LibGdx Game is Not Running in android?

Tags: android, libgdx

I am making a game using LibGdx framwork.This is working fine for dekstop but when try to run for android
       give exception:-

```
        12-03 10:39:46.687: E/AndroidRuntime(9487): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
       12-03 10:39:46.687: E/AndroidRuntime(9487): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.inoXmobile.glowjump.SuperJumper
        12-03 10:39:46.687: E/AndroidRuntime(9487):     at com.inoXmobile.glowjump.GlowJupmAndroid.onCreate(GlowJupmAndroid.java:35)
        12-03 10:39:46.687: E/AndroidRuntime(9487):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
        12-03 10:39:46.687: E/AndroidRuntime(9487):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
          12-03 10:39:46.687: E/AndroidRuntime(9487):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
          12-03 10:39:46.687: E/AndroidRuntime(9487):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
         12-03 10:39:46.687: E/AndroidRuntime(9487):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
           12-03 10:39:46.687: E/AndroidRuntime(9487):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
           12-03 10:39:46.687: E/AndroidRuntime(9487):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
          12-03 10:39:46.687: E/AndroidRuntime(9487):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
         12-03 10:39:46.687: E/AndroidRuntime(9487):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
          12-03 10:39:46.687: E/AndroidRuntime(9487):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
          12-03 10:39:46.687: E/AndroidRuntime(9487):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
          12-03 10:39:46.687: E/AndroidRuntime(9487):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
             12-03 10:39:46.687: E/AndroidRuntime(9487):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)I
```

**have put these jars and so file in android project libs folder:-**
  **1- gdx.jar

2-gdx-backend-android.jar

3-armeabi

4-armeabi-v7a**

**My Android Activity is:-**

```
public class GlowJupmAndroid extends AndroidApplication {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
         private PowerManager.WakeLock wl;
          Bundle next;
       @Override
     public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            this.initialize(new SuperJumper(), false);

          PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
         wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "DoNotDimScreen");
      }

      @Override
     protected void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       wl.acquire();
       }

 @Override
 protected void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
  wl.release();
 }
```

}

and my manifest file is this:-

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       package="com.inoXmobile.glowjump"
       android:versionCode="1"
       android:versionName="1.0"
       android:installLocation="auto">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:debuggable="true" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".GlowJupmAndroid"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
              android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
       </activity>

     </application>
     <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3"/>
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" /> 
 </manifest>
```

please anyone suggest me why this exception occure many time I have been try to remove project and try to run ,clean and and new jar download from cod.google,but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like the ADT 17 problem. A good explanation can be found [here](http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17), but the simplest approach is probably to follow the steps [here](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2362).